# How to enable trackpad tap to click in SDDM login page?

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt, sddm

I'm using Lubuntu 21.04. I would like to enable tap to click in the SDDM login screen. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Until you login LXQt is not involved as it's not been started when you're at the `sddm` greeter.  I'll refer you to https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/657 that may help

Comment: @guiverc Thank you! That solved the issue!

Comment: If you write up your solution in the answer section below, others can benefit from this question/answer, and you can gain some reputation points for the site. :)

Comment: Okay! I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [github](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/657)

If SDDM is running on Xorg, and you use libinput, just add Option "Tapping" "on" to a xorg conf file in /etc//X11/xorg.conf.d/
You can use this:

```
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-touchpad.conf
```

Paste the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"

        Option "Tapping" "on"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
        Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
EndSection
```